# Forcetype in httpd.conf not working

Tags: php, apache, lamp, friendly-url, httpd.conf

I want to use pretty url. So I searched net and tried to use the forcetype approach.

**httpd.conf:**

```
<Files "main">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

ls htdocs/
favicon.ico  index.php  main.php  webalizer  xampp
```

But this doesnot work. I tried to find the solution, as suggested I also tried following:

```
<Files "main">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>
```

---

```
<Files "main">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

---

```
<Files "main">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>
```

But nothing work. I am still getting `404 error` on opening `http://localhost/main`.

(`http://localhost/main.php` is working fine.)
I am using `xampp-linux-1.8.1` on `Linux abhi-me 3.0.0-31-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 20:02:57 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Why this is happening?**

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant use rewrites?

Comment: No I am just trying this, got error so I was trying to solve this, but was unable to. So seeking for help

Comment: I never used this method, but i suspect your file needs to be `main` instead of `main.php`. I think what this method is trying to do is make a file executable by php without having the `.php` extension

Comment: If I make it main and then try to open `http://localhost/main`, the main file gets downloaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you are trying to force the handler to be PHP5 doesn't mean that Apache will magically find a file named `/main.php` at `/main`.

You could simply rename `main.php` to `main` (while still having these handler rules in place) to make this work.  Otherwise if you want to keep the `.php` extension on your file, you will need to look at using a rewrite directive.